# mySQL: Assigning an auto increment ID number to a double select query

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am creating a program where data I select from one table is being randomly grouped. The RegistrationID number from each group is saved into another table (as a foreign key) and every group member is assigned a groupID that is auto incremented with every new group created.

```
$GroupSize = $_POST['groupsize'];

//Connect to the Server+Select DB
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbName) or die("Nope");

if (isset($_POST['create'])) {

//assign group id to groups created
//insert groupinformation to table from userInformation
      $query = "SELECT  RegistrationId FROM (Select * from userInformation order by RAND() LIMIT ".$GroupSize.") INTO groupInformation";
      $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die ("query failed" . mysqli_error($con));


//display group and information
    echo "<table border='1' >";
    echo "<tr><th>RegId</th><th>Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Email</th></tr>";
    while (($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) == true) {
        echo "<tr><td>$row[0]</td><td>$row[1]</td><td>$row[2]</td><td>$row[3]</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

//if group is less than 2 create error message

}

mysqli_close($con);
```

My problem is that I cannot assigned the GroupId to the extracted results because auto incremented numbers cannot be copied. This is my error:

```
query failed Every derived table must have its own alias
```

Here are my Table schemas

[image: Table schemas user]

[image: Table schemas group]

Comment: I get {query failed Undeclared variable: groupInformation}

Comment: Try this `"INSERT INTO groupInformation SELECT  RegistrationId FROM (Select * from userInformation order by RAND() LIMIT ".$GroupSize.") AS j"`

Comment: I get query failed Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Yes because you are trying to insert just single column `RegistrationId` into `groupInformation` table. You need to select same amount of columns as returned by `Select * from userInformation order by RAND()`

Comment: I still get the same error if I were to select just the RegistrationId and random group it.

Comment: If you want just single column try this `"INSERT INTO groupInformation(RegistrationId) SELECT RegistrationId FROM (Select * from userInformation order by RAND() LIMIT ".$GroupSize.") AS j"`

Comment: I'm not getting the error but every regID in the groupInformation table gets a separate groupID I need them to get the same groupID

Comment: What about this? `"INSERT INTO groupInformation(RegistrationId) SELECT RegistrationId FROM (Select *,RAND() AS RegistrationId from userInformation order by RegistrationId LIMIT ".$GroupSize.") AS j"`

Comment: I get query failed Duplicate column name 'RegistrationId'

Comment: Replace `RegistrationId`  with `randomRegistrationId ` random like: `"INSERT INTO groupInformation(RegistrationId) SELECT randomRegistrationId FROM (Select *,RAND() AS randomRegistrationId from userInformation order by randomRegistrationId LIMIT ".$GroupSize.") AS j"`

Comment: I get query failed Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`xyzcompany`.`groupinformation`, CONSTRAINT `groupinformation_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`RegistrationId`) REFERENCES `userInformation` (`RegistrationId`))

Comment: It seems your table `groupinformation` has `RegistrationId` as foreign key that references to `userInformation` table. But in query you are generating RANDOM number and inserting it to `groupinformation`. You need to have `RegistrationId` value in `userInformation` table before you can insert it into `groupinformation` table.

Comment: I am generating random rows by their Registration number that relate to the userInformation then giving an id number to each group created. Also the numbers are there.

Comment: Sorry, both of your screenshots belong to same table.

Comment: I have them fixed

Comment: If you want to save `RAND()` generated id to `GroupId` then you have to remove `AUTO_INCREMENT`. `"INSERT INTO groupInformation(randomRegistrationId,RegistrationId) SELECT randomRegistrationId,RegistrationId FROM (Select *,RAND() AS randomRegistrationId from userInformation order by randomRegistrationId LIMIT ".$GroupSize.") AS j"`

Comment: I get query failed Unknown column 'randomRegistrationId' in 'field list'

Comment: Sorry, try this `"INSERT INTO groupInformation(GroupId,RegistrationId) SELECT randomRegistrationId,RegistrationId FROM (Select *,RAND() AS randomRegistrationId from userInformation order by randomRegistrationId LIMIT ".$GroupSize.") AS j"`

Comment: i get query failed Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Answer (score 2):

Let `GroupId` autoincrement,then create one more column `RandomGroupId` in `groupInformation`, then paste the query:

```
INSERT INTO groupInformation(RandomGroupId,RegistrationId) 
SELECT randomRegistrationId,RegistrationId 
FROM (Select *,RAND() AS randomRegistrationId 
      FROM userInformation ORDER BY randomRegistrationId LIMIT ".$GroupSize."
      ) AS j
```

Comment: I get zeros as RandomGroupId.